# Blank image after normalizing RGB pixel values by dividing them with 255

Tags: python, image-segmentation

I am trying to turn 3D image into 2D. To do this, I normalized the pixel values by dividing them with 255 so that I can keep the values in a range from 0 to 1. However, I see my image turns completely dark instead.

Image - https://drive.google.com/open?id=1_LdTI8r4dHlqAfVvLIwMr6IoVKzy-9fH

```
from skimage.color import rgb2gray
import numpy as np
import cv2
#%matplotlib inline
'exec(%matplotlib inline)'
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import ndimage
from skimage import data

# read image and print RGB pixel values
pic = plt.imread('1.jpeg')/255  # dividing by 255 to bring the pixel values between 0 and 1
print(pic.shape)
plt.imshow(pic)
plt.show()

# reshaping 3D image to 2D
pic_n = pic.reshape(pic.shape[0]*pic.shape[1], pic.shape[2])
pic_n.shape
```

Comment: That is strange.

Comment: Agreed. It worked on another computer.

Answer (score 3):

I solved it myself.

```
from numpy import asarray
from PIL import Image

# load image
image = Image.open('1.jpeg')
pic = asarray(image)
# convert from integers to floats
pic = pic.astype('float32')
# normalize to the range 0-1
pic /= 255.0
plt.imshow(pic)
#plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have done is created an image with effectively RGB value (0, 0, 0) which is black. I have no idea what you were trying to accomplish.